# ¿Hay una traducción aceptada para "pretty print"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término, informática

He estado buscando un rato y no he podido encontrar una traducción, formal o informal de "pretty print" en español. No sé si es uno de esos términos en los que siempre se usa el anglicismo o si hay una traducción aceptada que yo no he sabido encontrar.

En algunos sitios mencionan `Coloración sintáctica` que a mí no me vale, porque si estoy en el *shell* de *MongoDB* no tengo colores de ningún tipo, pero al usar *find()* puedo decirle que me lo "haga bonito"  o **"más legible"** con db.col.find().pretty() y el "bonito" se debe al formateo del texto, en lugar de a la coloración. ¿Diría entonces que *Mongo* me lo está **"imprimiendo bonito"**, que es la traducción más literal?

Quizá se usa alguno de esos términos como "imprimir (más) legible" o "imprimir bonito" y yo simplemente no los he escuchado nunca.

¿Hay alguna traducción aceptada para el término [`pretty print`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint)<sup>*</sup> como lo entendemos en informática que es mejorar la presentación de un texto para que no salga como una fila de caracteres sino que se presente con los saltos de línea adecuados para mejorar la legibilidad del texto?

---

*La entrada es de la wikipedia. No deja de llamarme la atención que la entrada de "pretty print" no tiene traducción al español.

Comment: ¿Sería lo mismo que la _impresión elegante_ que se menciona [aquí](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/es/man1/muttprint.1.html)? Lo menciono sólo porque es así como lo traduce la WP francesa.

Comment: Me acaba de venir a la cabeza dos meses después «embellecer» o cualquiera de sus derivados.

Comment: ¿Qué tal **formato elegante**, **formato  legible** o **texto ordenado**?

Answer (score 5):

Lo he visto en herramientas IDE y editores de texto de desarrollo desde hace mucho tiempo y siempre se refiere a volver a dar formato al texto del código fuente que se está escribiendo.

Creo que algunas alternativas serían:

> (Re)formatear el código.
>
> Dar formato al código.
>
> Reordenar el código/texto.

Algunos "pretty prints" lo único que hacen es indentar el código sin capitalizar las palabras clave o adicionar saltos de línea por lo que "reindentar el código" también podría ser una opción.

EDICIÓN:

Atendiendo la observación de @guifa donde con toda razón dice que "indentar" es anglicismo debería entonces en su lugar utilizarse "sangrar" que tiene la siguiente definición según la RAE

> 5. tr. Impr. Empezar un renglón más adentro que los otros de la plana, como se hace con el primero de cada párrafo.

Veo un poco complicado que los desarrolladores comencemos a hablar de resangrar el código, pero el Español es el Español.

Comment: "Indentar" sería de hecho una buena en el caso de _MongoDB_, porque es así como lo pone "pretty". El problema es que muchas cosas distintas lo pueden hacer "pretty", pero en español no basta con "bonito" y los términos que describen la acción por supuesto no las van a abarcar todas. Aún así, gracias. +1 por la respuesta.

Comment: yeah, it basically means "arreglar el formato del código/texto" but that is not short and idiomatic.

Comment: @Diego «sangrar» sería mejor que «indentar» (anglicismo puro), ya que es la palabra más usada en tipografía y al hablar de la disposición de página

Comment: Gracias @guifa por la observación. Modifiqué mi respuesta, aunque ahora ya no sé si lo es.

Comment: He visto "sangrado" a veces.  https://javaparajavatos.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/sangrado-indentacion-y-tamano-de-las-lineas/

Answer (score 4):

Dado que como bien dices, el *pretty print* no tiene por qué ser en color, yo pondría:

> Mostrar con formato legible

no usaría **imprimir** porque en castellano se refiere a impresiones físicas con impresora, no a una pantalla. El equivalente de *display* sería mostrar por pantalla.

Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Como programador, creo que "**Formato mejorado**" sería la opción más ajustada a los escenarios en que se suele usar el término.

En ocasiones *pretty print* se usa para tomar un texto pensado para procesamiento y presentarlo de una manera legible, cierto; en otros casos, sin embargo, el texto ya es perfectamente legible, y lo único que se hace es ajustar un poco la indentación y añadir colores a los diferentes elementos. Es solo una manera de mejorar la presentación.

Lo anterior, rara vez tiene algo que ver con imprimir en papel el propio texto, con lo cual los calificativos "para impresión" y similares quedarían descartados, en mi opinión.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo traduciría como código formateado (sustantivo) / formatear código (verbo). EL formato puede agupar cualquiera de los atributos de lo "bonito", colores, indentado, espacios...

Answer (score 0):

En programación hablamos de "indentación".
En inglés *pretty print* es un nombre, que no le conozco traducción.
Sí existe el adjetivo *indentado* que se le puede aplicar al contenido que sea, por ejemplo "código indentado".

Comment: Como ya lo dijo antes @guifa, **indentar** es anglicismo.

Answer (score -1):

En los glosarios de Microsoft se traduce como **impresión con sangría**.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish Language! Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de tour y help center, que dan una introducción a la filosofía Stack. Una respuesta bien escrita responde a exactamente lo que se preguntó, aportando algo nuevo que no aparece en otra respuesta ya existente, y se documenta por medio de citas, fuentes, lógica, ejemplos, etc.