# Uso de "sangrar" en impresión

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, significado, terminología

Totalmente convencido de que en español existían las voces *indentar* e *indentación*, me encuentro con que no es así, y que los términos usados y aceptados por la RAE son ***[sangrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCj54xx)*** y ***[sangría](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCq62r8)***.

Viendo las acepciones de *sangrar*, me encuentro con que todas implican el flujo de algo (sangre, líquidos en generar, incluso resina y hasta bienes en el caso de hurtar). Pero no me imagino cómo llegó a usarse esta palabra para expresar:

> 5. tr. *Impr.* Empezar un renglón más adentro que los otros de la plana, como se hace con el primero de cada párrafo.

¿Qué hay en el proceso de desplazar un párrafo, visto desde el punto de vista del impresor, que justifique el uso de *sangrar* para describir esta acción?

---

P.D.: La voz *indentar* se viene [usando desde 1940](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indentar&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindentar%3B%2Cc0) más o menos, me pregunto si la RAE [la acabará aceptando](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17248/12637) algún día...

Comment: Pregunta similar: [Hay una traducción aceptada para “pretty print”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16081/1674)

Comment: Anda, pues parece que es algo que se introdujo hace bastante. Según el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) esta acepción se introdujo en la versión de 1817.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una [explicación](http://lapulpera.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/3-sangrias-3-primera.html) (no sé si verdadera, suena convincente) es esta: Para remarcar la delimitación de los párrafos (punto y aparte) uno de los primeros signos fue el [**calderón**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calder%C3%B3n_(tipograf%C3%ADa)) ( **¶** ) . En los manuscritos medievales tardíos más lujosos este solía dibujarse al comienzo de cada párrafo en color **rojo brillante (rojo sangre)**...

> En la Edad Media tardía, el calderón llegó a ser un signo ornamental estilizado, a menudo en rojo brillante; lo estampaba por un rubricador [*] especializado después de que el texto había sido escrito por los copistas, quienes dejaban espacios en blanco a propósito para tal fin. Sucedía a veces
>   que el [rubricador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubricaci%C3%B3n) no tenía tiempo para completar todos los ornamentos, y los espacios en blancos quedaban... El problema empeoró con la invención de la imprenta. Los primeros libros impresos dejaban espacios en blancos para los ornamentos a mano, incluyendo espacios para los calderones al comienzo de cada párrafo. Con el tiempo, los ornamentos desaparecieron, y los espacios quedaron.

(Traducido y resumido de [aquí](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/the-origin-of-the-pilcrow-aka-the-strange-paragraph-symbol-8610683/?no-ist))

[image]

(imagen de [aquí](http://voynichportal.com/tag/pilcrow/))

---

[*] De hecho, el sentido etimológico de "[rubricar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wn4lGEj)" es "colorear en rojo": *Del lat. tardío rubricāre 'enrojecer'*.

Comment: ¡Desde luego a mí me suena muy convincente! ¡Una historia muy interesante, y gracias por los enlaces y las imágenes!

Comment: Fantástica investigación, ¡qué curioso! Me recordó el origen de la expresión [_poner los puntos sobre las íes_](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-poner-los-puntos-sobre-las-ies/).

Comment: Al ver la pregunta, justo iba a decir que vendría del uso del colorado en los manuscritos.  E muy frecuente ver estos espacios en los incunables y en otros manuscritos medio hechos donde se supone que alguien iba a colorear y diseñar.  Era normal que los folios fuesen siendo dibujadas folio por folio, a veces con meses o años entre cada uno.  (es por eso que es tan común ver una página con márgenes extremadamente grandes, allí iban a dibujar).

Comment: @guifa pues qué pena que luego no se mantuvieran tales márgenes tan amplios. Hubiera permitido que [ciertos teoremas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) se pudieran demostrar allí : )