# ¿Cuál sería una alternativa a "indentación"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En [**esta pregunta**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/uso-de-sangrar-en-impresi%C3%B3n) ya se habló de que "**indentar**" e "**indentación**" no están aceptados por la RAE y que para el sentido de desplazamiento de texto los términos correctos son "**sangrar**" y "**sangría**".

Sin embargo, he visto que se utiliza en Oftalmología, con significados para los que parece necesario algún otro término. Así, se habla de la **indentación escleral** [aquí](http://www.docenciaoftalmologia.org/novedades-novedosas/indentacin-escleral) y [aquí](http://aberracionesespanglish.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/indentacion.html) o de la [**tonometría de indentación**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonometr%C3%ADa).

¿Qué palabra podría ser la adecuada para esos usos?

Comment: Si buscas la traducción de "indentation" en el [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu) del inglés al español, verás que en algunos casos se usa "indentación" y en otros no, dependiendo de cuál sea la palabra de uso corriente en cada ámbito concreto. Que no esté en el DRAE no significa que en un determinado ámbito no esté aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

Hace poco fedorqui nos descubrió el [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/), que nos va a venir al pelo para esta respuesta. Si ponemos "indentation" en su formulario y le ponemos el inglés como idioma de partida y el español como el de llegada, nos encontramos con varias opciones para traducir la palabra, según el ámbito:

- Ciencias biológicas:

  - Indentación.
- Electrónica y electrotécnica, Metalurgia y siderurgia, Ciencias de la tierra:

  - Huella.
- Informática y tratamiento de datos, Tratamiento de datos:

  - Sangrado.
- Industria mecánica, Transportes:

  - Dentado.
- Transporte terrestre, Industria mecánica, Transportes:

  - Muesca, escotadura.
- Informática y tratamiento de datos:

  - Sangría, sangrado.
- Ciencias biológicas:

  - Fragosidad.
- Metalurgia y siderurgia:

  - Corrugas, nervaduras.

Y así tres páginas llenas de opciones. No todos estos significados tienen por qué venir recogidos en la RAE, ya que se trata de palabras y términos muy concretos de determinados campos de la ciencia. Por tanto, si en oftalmología se usa "indentación" para determinadas expresiones, y son de uso amplio y aceptado dentro de ese campo, no veo por qué no se habría de seguir usando.

Recordemos siempre que es la RAE la encargada de recoger el uso de la expresión escrita, y no al revés. Tampoco me extrañaría que en un futuro acaben aceptando "indentación" como sinónimo de "sangría".

Además, si buscas en el CREA la palabra "indentación", te salen [tres ocurrencias](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=0&texto=indentaci%F3n&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000): dos hablan de "tonómetro de indentación" y una de "indentación escleral". No veo por tanto necesidad de buscar una nueva palabra.

Comment: Al fin y al cabo la RAE intenta registrar en el DRAE los usos generales de palabras, mientras que las que son típicas de algún sector determinado no tienen por qué estar incluidos. _Homología_, _inyectivo_, _exhaustivo_, _sesquilineal_... son palabras aceptadas en Matemáticas que no espero encontrar en el DRAE.

Comment: @fedorqui pues las dos primeras sí y tienen significados relacionados con la geometría o las matemáticas. La segunda está pero sin significado matemático, y la última directamente no está (aunque sí viene recogido el prefijo "[sesqui-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xj8cKOJ)").

Comment: ¡Ja! Debí haber buscado ejemplos más complicados :)