# ¿Cómo se podría mejorar la traducción de "syntactic sugar"?

Tags: expresiones, solicitud-de-término, informática, neologismos

El *syntactic sugar* o *[azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico)* (tal y como está recogido en la Wikipedia) son los "añadidos a la sintaxis de un lenguaje de programación diseñados para hacer algunas construcciones más fáciles de leer o expresar", poniendo como símil el propósito de hacer el lenguaje "más dulce". El ejemplo que estaba mirando justo ahora es la nueva forma de definir clases en JavaScript introducida con ECMAScript 2015:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

A mí la traducción de *azúcar sintáctico* se me antoja un tanto forzada y poco intuitiva, ya que al escucharla no me da la impresión de que se refiera a lo que en realidad se refiere. Como alternativa se me ocurrió *atajos sintácticos*, pero resulta que no siempre la mejora es un atajo, ya que a veces hacen las expresiones más largas: en COBOL la expresión `MOVE A B` tiene una alternativa que es `MOVE A TO B`, donde el `TO` es opcional y considerado *azúcar sintáctico* porque ayuda a entender la expresión. Así que la siguiente alternativa que se me ocurrió fue *ayudas sintácticas*.

¿Qué os parece? ¿Se os ocurre alguna otra alternativa que refleje de forma concisa e intuitiva lo que se intenta definir?

Comment: To be honest the phrase in English always seemed a bit strange to me so perhaps if it seems to you _tanto forzada y poco intuitiva_ it may be a very good translation.

Comment: Quizás usando facilitar, que describe la función del concepto: «sintaxis facilitante/facilitador».

Comment: Algunas ideas. *Sintaxis accesible, sintaxis facilitada, sintaxis amigable, sintaxis de colaboración, cosintaxis, sintaxis revisada, sintaxis humanista (o humanística), sintaxis de segundo ( o tercer) nivel, sintaxis nivelada, sintaxis asistiva, sintaxis dulce, sintaxis elaborada, sintaxis adornada, sintaxis elevada, el revisionismo sintáctio, sintaxis naturalista.*  Lo contrario: *sintaxis esqueleto, sintaxis tradicional, sintaxis básica, sintaxis sin adornos, sintaxis ras, sintaxis original, el purismo sintáctico, sintaxis desnuda, sintaxis deselevada, sintaxis desnivelada.*

Comment: @aparente001 una buena lista de propuestas. Elige la(s) que más te guste(n) y defiéndela(s) en una respuesta. :-)

Comment: Si tú escoges trataré de defender -- tú eres el que quiere poner el término en una frase, un párrafo, mejor dejo que tu elijas lo que queda con tu necesidad de comunicación.

Comment: *Sintaxis mejorada, sintaxis actualizada* vs. *sintaxis bruta* (cf. ingresos brutos), *sintaxis inicial*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si no te importa perder la aliteración, el concepto de dulzor y demás adornos... Una expresión algo más seria, que he visto usar en textos similares, sería «**conveniencia**»:

> **conveniencia**
>   1. f. Utilidad, provecho.
>   4. f. comodidad.
>
> **comodidad**
>   2. f. Cosa necesaria para vivir a gusto y con descanso.
>   4. f. Utilidad, interés.

La nueva sintaxis para definir clases en Javascript es una **conveniencia** introducida para hacer el código más legible (por ejemplo).

Answer (score 3):

Yo me decantaría por "Decoración sintáctica". Es como llenar tu casa de jarrones con flores. Seguiría siendo una casa sin ellos y seguiría cumpliendo su función, pero resulta más acogedora con flores.

Comment: No está mal, incluso podría sonar bien al revés: _sintaxis decorada_.

Answer (score 2):

Yo voy a continuar por el camino de lo dulce y proponer *sintaxis edulcorada*.

[Edulcorado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EOMGWoR) ( o [edulcorar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EOOfs0A))

> Dicho de un asunto: Mitigado en sus aspectos más desagradables o hirientes.
>
> Embellecido o mejorado falsamente.

Creo que el aspecto de "embellecido o mejorado" funciona para lo que queremos decir con "azúcar sintáctico". Estoy un poco en desacuerdo con la parte de "falsamente" en la definición, como si el uso de ciertos recursos para *edulcorar* fuera "ilícito" o "deshonesto" frente a los usados para *[azucarar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4gfjmOv)*.

Aparte, creo que "edulcorado" tiene ciertas connotaciones que no tendríamos con el uso de, por ejemplo, `embellecido`. A diferencia de lo que ocurre con un *pretty print* (que podríamos [traducir como "**formato** embellecido"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16081/5481)), con el azúcar sintáctico, como bien indicas en el ejemplo, podemos *añadir* para mejorar (como se hace al edulcorar).

Answer (score 1):

Me gustó lo de 'edulcorante', me parece que es algo que usamos en otros contextos (se me viene a la cabeza mentiras edulcoradas).

Creo que para que sea consistente con la frase original, *syntactic sugar*, la traducción apropiada debería ser en función de lo dulce, el sustantivo sería edulcorante, y lo relacionado a la sintaxis sería el adjetivo, por lo que sería lo más apropiado: **edulcorante sintáctico**.

Comment: Interesante aportación, Paolo. ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Seguro que en [tag:informática] encuentras otras preguntas similares en las que participar. Hasta pronto.

Answer (score 1):

¿por que no **sintaxis endulzada**? Ya se que los edulcorantes se llevan mucho en la actualidad, pero es cambiar azúcar por un elemento más artificial.

En cuanto a lo de formato embellecido me recuerda al *prettyprint*, el formato elegante, que también ayuda a la lectura, aunque no añade elementos opcionales a la sintaxis.